# Strange issue with soft Keyborad when i click on Edit Text's and go to background

Tags: android, keyboard, window, homescreen

I use in this code to hide soft keyboard in case that appliation go background:

> this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

I have screen's and view's  with some edit text(this edit text are custom view). when I click on edit text and move the next edit text by press on view itself(not by click on next in keyboard) and then  press on home button, in most of the case the soft keyboard dont hide. **It's seems that i have some softkeyboard open one each other**!!

If i click on one edit text and go to background the soft keyboard is hiding.

Why it's happen? why setSoftInputMode dont work in this case?

Comment: Have you got any other views in the stack that have the softkeyboard open?

Comment: Now i think. this view are custom view. maybe this occurs to this issue?